# "RDLC" How to set a Dynamic Header

Tags: c#, rdlc

Here is my requirement, I need to have a page header which may vary from every pages. 
here is some example:

[The first page of the report, it seems normal on first record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGwhN.png)

[However when it comes to second record, the page header won't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNZwl.png)

This is my expression in rdlc i have tried

- ="Staff No: " +  ReportItems!STAFF_NO2.Value
  (The id in table field which contains the staff_no value)
- ="Staff No: " +  Fields!STAFF_NO.Value
- ="Staff No: " +  first(Fields!STAFF_NO.Value)

Unfortunately, it is still not working
Any Genius Can me ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked Microsoft, their response was "RDLC Has a limitation dynamic page header is not support while exported to word "
Hope Microsoft will fix it lol